# agora web sdk (video calling) remote user screen sharing status

Tags: javascript, video, screensharing, agora

I am working on agora web sdk (video calling) pure javascript. I integrated video calling and it is working. when remote users share the screen, not getting any screen-sharing status to update the UI. I tried so many ways using user-published events but didn't work. in this event, both video track and screen track sharing screen kind status is video only. I want to detect remote users' screen-sharing status. Please anyone let me know. Here I am using pure javascript, not npm.

need to know agora web sdk remote users screen sharing status